# SharePoint 2010 - Audience - Navigation permissions

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, audience-targeting, audiences

I added a link to our Navigation that I want audienced to a specific group, whether it be an Active Directory group, or a custom audience that we setup in Central Admin.  When I attempt to audience the link that is in the navigation, the link never shows up.

I have verified the user is in the group that I have in that specific audience.  I have also tried creating a custom audience in Central Admin and then adding the AD group to that audience.  The users show up in the audience but the link will not show.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I meet the same issue, how to config the DC to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Is the active directory group a nested group or are all members added directly to the group. Nested groups as far as i know are not supported by the audiences.

If you have a custom audience make sure that the audience is compiled, otherwise SharePoint didn't know who is in the audience.

You will find more information on audience here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263065.aspx

For the compilation you will find more information here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263278

Comment: I have reviewed these and I am doing exactly everything these are saying.

Comment: Also, the Active Directory group is not a nested group.

Comment: Have you check the log after the audience compilation?

Comment: Where is the log?  In the Compilation errors area it says: No error

Comment: On the server normally C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\logs\

Comment: So, I have found that the Domain Admins didn't grant my user profile user the correct permissions on all of the DCs.  Once that was done that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found that the Domain Admins didn't grant my user profile user the correct permissions on all of the DCs.  Once that was done that resolved my issue.